# ClassCastException during reading collection with java app through spark cluster

Tags: java, mongodb, apache-spark

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy to field org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.DataSourceRDDPartition.inputPartitions of type scala.collection.Seq in instance of org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.DataSourceRDDPartition
```

```
SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder()
                .master("spark://localhost:7077")
                .appName("MongoSparkConnectorIntro")
                .config("spark.mongodb.read.connection.uri", "mongodb://127.0.0.1/testdb.balances")
                .config("spark.mongodb.write.connection.uri", "mongodb://127.0.0.1/testdb.balances")
                .getOrCreate();
        Dataset<Row> df = spark.read().format("mongodb")
                .load();
        df.printSchema();
        df.show();
```

My app is running on host machine.My java app connected to the spark master on the docker. Then connected mongo successfully. df.printSchema(); is working shows columns.
root

```
 |-- Data_value: double (nullable = true)
 |-- Group: string (nullable = true)
 |-- MAGNTUDE: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- Period: double (nullable = true)
 |-- STATUS: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Series_reference: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Series_title_1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Subject: string (nullable = true)
 |-- UNITS: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _id: string (nullable = true)
```

But when try to show items of collection, it throws class.CastException. my app includes spark 3.4.1 version dependencies, jdk 17, and also spark master on the docker is 3.4.1 version.

When I set sparksession master local. It works perfectly. but when  I tried to add my app jar files SparkSession with cluster like session

```
spark.config("spark.jars","target/spark-demo.jar")
```

but it is not fixed

Comment: Check your Scala versions, there is a mismatch, and they must all be the same (2.12 or 2.13 for 3.4.1).

Comment: how to check version compatibility , on the docker scala version 2.12.17, in pom.xml spark 3.4.1 version

Comment: search through the classpath on the spark gui environment looking for a mismatch in the jar name.  Note, if it's a shared cluster it may have been other users who added a mismatched jar, if not you may check your own IDE for different scala libraries

Comment: should I search scala library or scala reflect?